# Showing content of the next html page according to buttons clicked in the first html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a site which is basically a app store for my own apps.
[image]

I want to show info (eg. screenshots , app size, requirements, permissions etc.) of whichever app icon user clicks in this html file (see the image).
Making html files for each app separately is not a great idea i think.
(can i achieve this without any other frameworks)

Here's the code of first html file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>TZStore</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/apps_store.css"/>
  
  <!--Fonts-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tapestry&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Endfonts-->
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="root">
    <!-------NAV_Bar--------->
    <nav class="nav-root">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/profile.png" alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <div class="label">TZStore</div>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-------NAV_Bar--------->
    <div class="icon_grid">
<div class="item">
    <a id="button" href="app_preview.html">
        <img src="app_icons/calculator1.0.png"/>
    </a>
    <span class="caption">Calculator1.0</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
   <a href="app_preview.html"> <img src="app_icons/tictactoe.png"/> </a>
    <span class="caption">TicTacToe</span>
</div>

<div class="icon_grid icon_grid">
    
<div class="item">
   <a href="app_preview.html"> <img src="app_icons/baseConverter.png"/> </a>
    <span class="caption">BaseConverter</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
   <a href="app_preview.html"> <img src="app_icons/marksPercentage.png"/>
   </a>
    <span class="caption">Marks-Percentage</span>
</div>
</div>

    
    </div>
    <!---root end -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css of it.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


.root {
    height: 80rem;
    width: 100%;
    color: red;
    background-image: linear-gradient(95deg, #2196f3, #7b81ed, #b365d4, #d941aa, #eb1274);
}


.nav-root {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    /*background-color: #b200ff;*/
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: fixed;
}


/*
padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #77aaff;
    box-shadow:  -1px 1px #77aaff,
         -2px 2px #77aaff,
         -3px 3px #77aaff,
         -4px 4px #77aaff,
         -5px 5px #77aaff;
}*/

.logo img {
    width: 40px;
    position: relative;
    right: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
}

.label {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Tapestry', cursive;
    margin-left: 0;
    /*width: 200px;*/
    /*background-color: cyan;*/
}

.burger {
    height: 40px;
    width: 45px;
}

.line {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
    height: 5px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px 3px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.title-text {
    font-family: 'Tapestry', cursive;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
/*  background-color: #00ccff;*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 20px
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.icon {
    /* To correctly align image, regardless of content height: */
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 45%;
    background-color: green;
    /* To horizontally center images and caption */
    text-align: center;
    /* The width of the container also implies margin around the images. */
}

.caption {
    /* Make the caption a block so it occupies its own line. */
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Tapestry', cursive;
    color: white;
}

.iconjsj {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    top: 300px;
    left: 45%;
}
.icon img{
    width: 60px;
}

.icon_grid {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    top: 150px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    /*background-color: pink;*/
    
}

.icon_grid2 {
    top: 170px;
}



.item {
    /* To correctly align image, regardless of content height: */
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    /* To horizontally center images and caption */
    text-align: center;
    /* The width of the container also implies margin around the images. */
    width: 120px;
   / background-color: orange;*/
}

.item img{
    width: 40px;
box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
}

.caption {
    /* Make the caption a block so it occupies its own line. */
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Your question is really broad and almost impossible to answer as it stands. You can fetch data (requirements, etc.) from an API or get it from a JSON file, then have some JavaScript fill in the fields in a generic HTML page. TL;DR: Start by creating the page you want your app details to be on and then use some JavaScript (see: document.getElementById or document.getElementsByClassName) to change the displayed text in each field.

Comment: ok..sorry i can't explain my problems properly, but now i working on it the other way.. thanks.